# Convert index table to character matrix (or df)? in R

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I keep getting weird errors.  The logic seems sound to me.  Can you look at the code below and provide some insight please?  Thanks.

```
    rw      <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
    cl      <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
    ch      <- c("A","bv","c","dog","cat","bird","red", "yel","fuscia")
    df      <- data.frame(rw, cl, ch)
    df
    layout  <- matrix(NA, nrow=3, ncol=3)
    layout[df[,1:2]] <- df[,3]
```

The error is:

```
Error in layout[df[, 1:2]] <- df[, 3] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking with your original plan, matrix indexing requires a `matrix`, not a `data.frame`

```
layout[as.matrix(df[,1:2])] <- as.character(df[,3])
```

...will work (after some adjustment to make sure that your `factor` data is converted to `character` form). Your error is essentially saying you can't index using a `list` (or `data.frame`, which is a type of list).